# retrieve value of maximum occurrence in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am in a very complicated problem. Let me explain you first what I am doing right now:

I have a table name `feedback` in which I am storing grades against course id. The table looks like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+--------------
| id    | cid   | grade |g_point| workload  | easiness
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+--------------
| 1     |  10   |  A+   |   1   |      5    |   4
| 2     |  10   |  A+   |   1   |      2    |   4
| 3     |  10   |  B    |   3   |      3    |   3
| 4     |  11   |  B+   |   2   |      2    |   3
| 5     |  11   |  A+   |   1   |      5    |   4
| 6     |  12   |  B    |   3   |      3    |   3
| 7     |  11   |  B+   |   2   |      7    |   8
| 8     |  11   |  A+   |   1   |      1    |   2
```

`g_point` has just specific values for the grades, thus I can use these values to show the user courses sorted by grades.

Okay, now first my task is to print out the `grade` of each course. The `grade` can be calculated by the maximum occurrence against each course. For example from this table we can see the result of `cid = 10` will be `A+`, because it is present two times there. This is simple. I have already implemented this query which I will write here in the end.

The main problem is when we talk about the course `cid = 11` which has two different grades. Now in that situation client asks me to take the average of workload and easiness of both these courses and whichever course has the greater average should be shown. The average would be computed like this:

```
  all workload values of the grade against course
+ all easiness values of the grade against course
/ 2
```

From this example `cid = 11` has four entries,have equal number of grades against a course

**`B+` grade average**

```
avgworkload(2 + 7)/2=x 
avgeasiness(3 + 8)/2 = y
```

answer x+y/2 = 10

**`A+` grade average**

```
 avgworkload(5 + 1)/2=x 
avgeasiness(4 + 2)/2 = y

  answer x+y/2 = 3
```

so the grade should be `B+`.

This is the query which I am running to get the max occurrence grade

```
SELECT
    f3.coursecodeID cid,
    f3.grade_point p,
    f3.grade g
FROM (
    SELECT
        coursecodeID,
        MAX(mode_qty) mode_qty
    FROM (
        SELECT
            coursecodeID,
            COUNT(grade_point) mode_qty
        FROM feedback
        GROUP BY
            coursecodeID, grade_point
    ) f1
    GROUP BY coursecodeID
) f2
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        coursecodeID,
        grade_point,
        grade,
        COUNT(grade_point) mode_qty
    FROM feedback
    GROUP BY
        coursecodeID, grade_point
) f3
ON
    f2.coursecodeID = f3.coursecodeID AND
    f2.mode_qty = f3.mode_qty
GROUP BY f3.coursecodeID
ORDER BY f3.grade_point
```

Comment: if u wanted workload + easiness, shouldn't it be `2+3` and `5+4`?

Comment: oh yes. let me correct it

Comment: In your sample data grade `A+` has `workload=5` and `easiness=4` for `id=1`, but for `id=2` same grade `A+` has different `workload=2` and `easiness=4`. Is it a typo or indeed these values can vary? If it is a typo and they can't vary, then it's easy. If they can, then please add two more rows to your sample data and tell us how the result should be calculated: `id=7, cid=11, grade=B+, workload=7, easiness=8` . `id=8, cid=11, grade=A+, workload=1 and easiness=2`

Comment: @VladimirBaranov can you please check my question. I have updated the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/165ea/5/0).
I added a table `Courses` with the list of all course IDs, to make the main idea of the query easier to see. Most likely you have it in the real database. If not, you can generate it on the fly from `feedback` by grouping by `cid`.

For each `cid` we need to find the `grade`. Group `feedback` by `cid, grade` to get a list of all grades for the `cid`. We need to pick only one grade for a `cid`, so we use `LIMIT 1`. To determine which grade to pick we order them. First, by occurrence - simple `COUNT`. Second, by the average score. Finally, if there are several grades than have same occurrence and same average score, then pick the grade with the smallest `g_point`. You can adjust the rules by tweaking the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT
  courses.cid
  ,(
    SELECT feedback.grade
    FROM feedback
    WHERE feedback.cid = courses.cid
    GROUP BY
      cid
      ,grade    
    ORDER BY 
      COUNT(*) DESC
      ,(AVG(workload) + AVG(easiness))/2 DESC
      ,g_point
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS CourseGrade
FROM courses
ORDER BY courses.cid
```

**result set**

```
cid CourseGrade
10  A+
11  B+
12  B
```

**UPDATE**

MySQL doesn't have lateral joins, so one possible way to get the second column `g_point` is to repeat the correlated sub-query. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/165ea/6/0)

```
SELECT
  courses.cid
  ,(
    SELECT feedback.grade
    FROM feedback
    WHERE feedback.cid = courses.cid
    GROUP BY
      cid
      ,grade    
    ORDER BY 
      COUNT(*) DESC
      ,(AVG(workload) + AVG(easiness))/2 DESC
      ,g_point
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS CourseGrade
  ,(
    SELECT feedback.g_point
    FROM feedback
    WHERE feedback.cid = courses.cid
    GROUP BY
      cid
      ,grade    
    ORDER BY 
      COUNT(*) DESC
      ,(AVG(workload) + AVG(easiness))/2 DESC
      ,g_point
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS CourseGPoint
FROM courses
ORDER BY CourseGPoint
```

**result set**

```
cid CourseGrade CourseGPoint
10  A+          1
11  B+          2
12  B           3
```

**Update 2** Added average score into `ORDER BY` [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/165ea/8/0)

```
SELECT
  courses.cid
  ,(
    SELECT feedback.grade
    FROM feedback
    WHERE feedback.cid = courses.cid
    GROUP BY
      cid
      ,grade    
    ORDER BY 
      COUNT(*) DESC
      ,(AVG(workload) + AVG(easiness))/2 DESC
      ,g_point
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS CourseGrade
  ,(
    SELECT feedback.g_point
    FROM feedback
    WHERE feedback.cid = courses.cid
    GROUP BY
      cid
      ,grade    
    ORDER BY 
      COUNT(*) DESC
      ,(AVG(workload) + AVG(easiness))/2 DESC
      ,g_point
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS CourseGPoint
  ,(
    SELECT (AVG(workload) + AVG(easiness))/2
    FROM feedback
    WHERE feedback.cid = courses.cid
    GROUP BY
      cid
      ,grade    
    ORDER BY 
      COUNT(*) DESC
      ,(AVG(workload) + AVG(easiness))/2 DESC
      ,g_point
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS AvgScore
FROM courses
ORDER BY CourseGPoint, AvgScore DESC
```

**result**

```
cid CourseGrade CourseGPoint    AvgScore
10  A+          1               3.75
11  B+          2               5
12  B           3               3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. one issue. I want to order By grade_point. But It isn't working with my database. I am getting order by courses.cid which I don't need. and I don't know where to i add this order by grade_point in the query

Comment: @hellosheikh, I added a second variant

Comment: okay Thank you very much. I am away from my computer right now. I will test it and get back to you. Thank you very much for all the help @Vladimir Baranov

Comment: is it possible to sort the data based on average as well. I mean Sort based on grade_point and if 2 courses are the same pick the course with the highest overall average? If it isn't its okay. you were already great help to me @VladimirBaranov

Comment: @hellosheikh, the straight-forward way is to repeat the sub-query third time. I don't really know if there is an efficient way to do it in MySQL.

Comment: @ VladimirBaranov just repeat the query without any changes?

Comment: @hellosheikh, see the updated answer. Yes, I repeated the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well you need an inner select to find the average, and a second outer select to find the maximum values of the average

```
select cid, grade, max(average)/2 from (
    select cid, grade, avg(workload + easiness) as average
    from feedback
    group by cid, grade
) x group by cid, grade
```

This solution has been tested on your data usign sql fiddle at this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c34a/5)

If you change the previous query to

```
select cid,  max(average)/2 from (
    select cid, grade, avg(workload + easiness) as average
    from feedback
    group by cid, grade
) x group by cid
```

You will find the max average for each cid.

As mentioned in the comments you have to choose wich strategy use if you have more grades that meets the max average. For example if you have

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+--------------
| id    | cid   | grade |g_point| workload  | easiness
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+--------------
| 1     |  10   |  A+   |   1   |      5    |   4
| 2     |  10   |  A+   |   1   |      2    |   4
| 3     |  10   |  B    |   3   |      3    |   3
| 4     |  11   |  B+   |   2   |      2    |   3
| 5     |  11   |  A+   |   1   |      5    |   4
| 9     |  11   |  C    |   1   |      3    |   6
```

You will have grades A+ and C soddisfing the maximum average 4.5

Comment: thanks for your answer But It is getting the multiple results. I mean there should be one grade against each particular course

Comment: Yes this is the basis to get the results. But note that there can be more grades that soddisf the solution you search, so it is not possible to have only one row, or yoou need to hide the grade or you need to combine more grades in one column

Comment: well its kinda confusing to me. I mean if there are multiple enteries against the course how am I going to know which to hide or which to show?

Comment: I edited the answer to show you a possible multiple solution for same course (at the end of answer)

Comment: ok so you mean I can't use both the stratergies average and max occurance in one query ? I mean if result can't come from maximum occurance use the average ?

Comment: No, I say that the maximum is not always defined by one single value. It can be  defined by multiple values. Just to simplify it: Find the oldest person in this set of people: Frank (40 yo), Anna (39yo), James (40yo), Luke (40yo), Jeff (38 yo). The answer is not done by one persone, but by three (Frank, James, Luke)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83022/discussion-between-davide-lorenzo-marino-and-hellosheikh).

Comment: sorry I slept. Please comment here when you come online